# Java: getting subclass reference using getClass

Tags: java

If i have a superclass called Animal, and subclasses called Cat, Dog, Bird.

If I read an array of Animals, and want to access a Cat specific method called meow(), how do i do this?

I know i can use getClass() to find out the Animal's subclass, but how do i use to create a reference to access meow()

Comment: You may have to change to use the `instanceof` because you may also have subclassed the `Cat` class where you may also want to call the `meow` method.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast to `Cat`

```
if (animal.getClass().getName().equals('Cat')) {
    ((Cat)animal).meow();
}
```

Or you could use `instanceof`.

---

Both of those solutions are ugly, and Java was not designed to be used this way.  Instead, you should create a `.speak` method for the animals that could call `Cat.meow` internally.

Comment: If i have a speak() method, and i have 20 animal subclasses, and i have to dynamically refer to Cat's speak method, how would i do that? I can't have a getClass.equals() for all the 20 animals.

Comment: @stumped are you saying that you *only* want the Cat to speak?

Comment: No, i mean, i'm reading an array of Animals, say there are 100 animal subclasses, and i need to find out which subclass it is, and then call its speak method. I don't know how to dynamically create a subclass reference.

Comment: @stumped you have to cast as I showed in my example (and many others did).  This is *not* how you should be using Java.  All 100 animals should implement a `speak` method and you should just call `animal.speak` and not care what the animal actually is

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an array of `animal`s, you need to check whether the object you are working with is an instance of `Cat` class, this can be achieved by using the [instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator. Then we can use the [downcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) operator to convert the `Animal` to a `Cat` and then call the `meow()` method.

```
if(animal instanceof Cat){
    (Cat)animal.meow()
}
```

With an array

```
Animal [] animals = [];
foreach(Animal animal: animals){
    //do something

    if(animal instanceof Cat){
        (Cat)animal.meow()
    }
}
```

Comment: @stumped : This is more proper way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ...

```
if (animal.getClass().getName().equals('Cat')) {
    ((Cat)animal).meow();
}
```

or

```
if (animal instanceof Cat) {
    ((Cat)animal).meow();
}
```

Comment: But what if you only know it is Cat dynamically from getClass()

Answer (score 0):

Once you found out the subclass you want to use, you can cast it. In your case it would be

```
((Cat)animals[index]).meow();
```